# Dynatree: Accessing the auto-allocated key of a dropped node

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am interfacing dynatree to a relational database. I drag and drop nodes from a source tree into a target tree. When the drop is complete I need to access the unique key value automatically assigned to the dropped node in the target tree. I am using:

copynode = sourceNode.toDict(true, function(dict){
...
delete dict.key; // Remove key, so a new one will be created
});

I need the unique node key value because you can't depend on node names for uniqueness. Once I've got the key I can figure out where in the tree the node was dropped and update the database. How do you get the new node key?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `node.addChild(copynode)`: this function returns the first newly created node, which should contain the new key.

Another option would be to generate and set your own unique key, instead of removing it and depending on Dynatree to create one.